# How do I make the code which execute the python file (not itself) with input redirection?

Tags: python, input, io, io-redirection

I want to make call.py which execute main.py with input redirection of input.txt.

In addition to that,I don't want to change the code of main.py.

What I want to do is like below.

call.py

```
exec(open("./main.py").read() < input.txt)
```

Of course I know that this code doesn't work.

main.py

```
name=input()
x=int(input())
print(name +" has chosen "+str(x)+".")
```

input.txt

```
Alice
2
```

Please give me the advice for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `subprocess` module for this. A sample usage is shown below.

In **call.py**:

> proc = subprocess.Popen( "main.py input.txt", stdout =
>   subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE )

All you have to do in **main.py** is read the contents of *input.txt* by using the `sys` module. To fetch *input.txt* from the command line, use `sys.argv[1]`.

Comment: I'm sorry for the lack of information in the question.I don't want to change the code of main.py.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't feed the contents of input.txt directly to main.py by passing through call.py. This is dealing with 2 different streams: the file and stdin stream. You can't "future-feed" a text file's content to another python script's stdin stream.

Answer (score 0):

Just writing this is enough:

```
os.system('main.py < input.txt')
```